# How to accept onSingleTapUp() on inner view while accept onFling() on outer view?

Tags: android, gesture, ontouchlistener

I have a view that covers entire screen (let's say `ParentView`), and child inner view `ChildView` that covers only portion of it.
I want to make `ChildView` to respond to `onSingleTapUp()`, while the `ParentView` respond to `onFling()`. I am trying to do so by attaching one `SimpleOnGestureListener` on `ChildView` and one `SimpleOnGestureListener` on `ParentView`.

To accept `onSingleTapUp()` from `ChildView`, its listener's `onDown()` has to return true. 
But once I do that, the listener tied to `ParentView` does not hear any motion events anymore since it is taken by the `ChildView`'s listener. Even though `ChildView`'s `onFling()` returns false, the events do not flow to the `ParentView`'s listener.

**How can I make the parent view's listener catch the fling gesture while child view's listener catch tap gesture?**

I don't think any source code is needed to explain the situation, but here is a snippet that sets up my `ChildView` listener.

```
ChildView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
        return singleTapGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(motionEvent);
    }
});
```

One workaround could be to have both `ParentView` and `ChildView`'s listeners to handle `onFling()` while only `ChildView`'s listener handle `onSingleTapUp()`, but in that case, fling won't be able to happen across the `ChildView` (like start outside the child and then end within the child), I believe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't like my solution, but I found a way to do this. Hopefully somebody else will post better answer in the future, or at least my workaround is useful to somebody otherwise.

As I described in the question, the problem lies on how gesture listener works. For child view to catch `onSingleTapUp()` event, you return true on `onDown()`. But once you do that, the subsequent series of events won't go to the parent view even after your child view's `onTouch()` declares it is no longer interested in the event. If you forcefully call the parent's `onTouch()` within the child's `onTouch()` when its gesture detector returns false, yes the parent's onFling() will be invoked but the first `MouseEvent` argument will be NULL since it was consumed by the child view's `onTouch()`.

I must be missing something since this seems very basic gesture detection scenario. Anyway, I couldn't find a way to do this in reasonable way.

So, my workaround is to make TouchListenerService as a singleton.

**Both child view and parent view have this line**:

```
view.setOnTouchListener(TouchListenerService.Instance());
```

and TouchListenerService starts like this:

```
public class TouchListenerService
    extends GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener
    implements View.OnTouchListener {

    // some code to implement singleton

    public SingleTapUpHandler SingleTapUpHandler;
    public FlingHandler FlingHandler;

    private View _touchingView;

    GestureDetector gestureDetector;

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
        if (gestureDetector == null)
            gestureDetector =  new GestureDetector(_touchListenerService);

        _touchingView = view;
        boolean result = gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(motionEvent);
        _touchingView = null;
        return result;
    }
    // and some more code
```

Since it is the same event handler, parent view catches `onFling()` event successfully while child view can set `SingleTapUpHandler` to process click event.

Comment: This is working well for me and I tried other ways but did not work, like using FrameLayout - same problem there. Accepting this as answer - hopefully it will help others in the future, or somebody else will note better way to do it.